# Personal notes area

Tags: feature-request

I would like to suggest implementing a simple "personal notes" section in the user page. This could hold things to help dig up resources, references, documentation etc., things such as:

- Links to often used off-site resources as well as specific answers (not favorites), but also to images, audio, video etc. that often are used with for example JavaScript, video, audio, canvas etc. (just example)
- Short text snippets that can be copied and pasted (useful when moderating/helping new users)
- Snippet templates (that can be selected when in snippet editor).

Personally I would really like to see something related to snippet templates in particular as I find my self writing much of the same setup code over and over when using snippets.

Yes, there are tools out there that can do some of these things, but not everyone uses those, and keeping it collected on the site keeps it easily and always accessible regardless of device/location one chose to ask/answer from.

A simple mock-up:

[image: mockup]

Comment: There is already GitHub Gists which does something similar. I'm not convinced this is really needed.

Comment: @JonasCz it's probably not *needed* per-se, but as many tools it can make things more efficient. Removes dependencies on sites such as github etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why spend time and effort implementing something that other services have already created and that will work better than what you can achieve in any reasonable amount of time?

Stick Evernote in your chroam.

[image]

<sup>Well, I figured you'd speculate on what I blanked out, anyhow.</sup>

Comment: Now I'm kind of curious what personal notes you take on porn

Comment: @Pekka웃 Hash function based on the angle of the dangle and the booty of the cutie.

Comment: @K3N You have many options.  That doesn't mean every *thing* has to be engineered to serve your every whim.  Frankly, that's an *immature* desire.  When you grow up, you realize it's better to identify a small set of related goals and concentrate on them, making them as perfect as possible.  Should *all* knives be swiss army knives?  Also, get a sense of humor.  It makes life more pleasant.

Comment: You need some note app on every devices, but i have this functionality in one source (website). Why StackOverflow can't store link to note(post, answer, etc.) in your profile ?) In profile we have favourite but can't add to favourites any answer in question (((